# Putty / SSH with a virtual console width of 2000 characters

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, console

When I use `putty.exe` to SSH a Linux server, I usually use a console width of ~ 160 columns (configurable in the Putty settings, *Window* tab).

But even with this, when you do things like `cat /var/log/apache2/access.log`, each line is broken in two lines which makes it difficult to read. Of course `cat ... | cut -c 1-160` could help but then the rest of the line is not displayed.

**Question: on Windows, how to SSH a Linux server, with a virtual console width of, say, 2000 characters, and a horizontal scrollbar?**

TL;DR instead of this:

[image]

I'd like this, with a horizontal scrollbar and a very large console width:

[image]

---

**Edit**: I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally on already-written files, on currently-being-updated files (such as Apache logs), **but also in realtime on the ouptut of, for example a Python script** like this:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i)*200)
    time.sleep(1)
```

How to see the output of this script without line-breaks in the terminal, but still see the output being written in realtime, and not have:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
...
...
```

but instead:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000...
1111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

with the ability to scroll horizontally?

In this case doing `python script.py |less -S` does not work: it is not displayed second after second in realtime.
Doing `python script.py |less -S +F` does not work either because the horizontal scrolling -S cannot be used at the same time of the "tail -f mode".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `less -S` to read the files.

Comment: Thank you @user1686 for this answer, it is very useful for logs! How would you do to apply this method also to the output of a Python script? I've added an Edit at the end of my question to explain what I mean. Thanks in advance if you have an idea!

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the accepted answer, for future readers/future reference:

- If you want to visualize a constantly-updated log the way described in the question, you can either do:

  ```
  less +F -S access.log
  ```

  It will then be in "tail -f mode", showing *Waiting for data...(interrupt to abort)"*. To quit this mode, you can do <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.
- Another way is to do:

  ```
  less +G -S access.log
  ```

  which automatically positions the cursor at the end of the end, but does *not* auto-update the display in real-time (in the case new data is appended). In the case you want to enter this "tail -f mode", doing <kbd>SHIFT+F</kbd> is helpful.

---

Important note: while in auto-updating "tail -f mode", you cannot scroll horizontally with the arrow keys, you have to quit this mode with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, then move horizontally, and then redo <kbd>SHIFT+F</kbd> to re-enter in "tail -f mode".